# How to remove the two lowest numbers from a listbox in Visual Basic 2015?

Tags: vb.net

Ok so I'm supposed to have the user input up to 13 grades, then have them averaged after removing the two lowest grades. I can't figure out what to use to remove the two lowest grades, whether it be from the listbox or during the calculation. Here's my code so far:

```
    Dim strGrades As String
    Dim decGrades As Decimal = 0
    Dim decAverage As Decimal = 0
    Dim decTotal As Decimal = 0

    Dim strInputMessage As String = "Enter grade #"
    Dim strInputHeading As String = "Grade"
    Dim strNormalMessage As String = "Enter grade #"
    Dim strNonNumericError As String = "Error - Please enter a grade"
    Dim strNegativeError As String = "Error - Please enter a positive number"

    Dim strCancelClicked As String = ""
    Dim intMaxNumberOfEntries As Decimal = 13
    Dim intNumberOfEntries As Decimal = 1

    strGrades = InputBox(strInputMessage & intNumberOfEntries, strInputHeading, " ")

    Do Until intNumberOfEntries > intMaxNumberOfEntries Or strGrades = strCancelClicked
        If IsNumeric(strGrades) Then
            decGrades = Convert.ToDecimal(strGrades)
            If decGrades >= 0 Then
                lstGrades.Items.Add(decGrades)
                decTotal += decGrades
                intNumberOfEntries += 1
                strInputMessage = strNormalMessage
            Else
                strInputMessage = strNegativeError
            End If
        Else
            strInputMessage = strNonNumericError
        End If

        If intNumberOfEntries <= intMaxNumberOfEntries Then
            strGrades = InputBox(strInputMessage & intNumberOfEntries, strInputHeading, " ")
        End If

    Loop
    lstGrades.Sorted = True
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have an enumerable list of numeric values, e.g. an array of `Decimal`, then the most succinct way to get the average of all but the two lowest values would be:

```
Dim average = myList.OrderBy(Function(n) n).Skip(2).Avg()
```

I'm not sure how much of that would be acceptable for an assignment - if that's what this is - but the part that you're asking about specifically can still be done by calling `Skip(2)` if you start with a list that is sorted in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

You can count the entries in the list box and remove the bottom 2 entries.

You can add them to a list and sort it.

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue, the OP doesn't want to remove the bottom 2, they want to remove the lowest 2 in terms of their value.

Comment: Doesn't sorting a list (of integer) sort in descending order? The lowest two values would be past and you could just remove the elements. I couldn't remember if sorting the list box would work but I think they have to be strings which means they'll sort alphabetical which won't help the OP. I thought arrays and lists sorted numerically.